# How to remove text from a string that is not surrounded by HTML tags?

Tags: php, html, regex

So basically I have a large sting (few paragraphs long).

I need to remove all text from this string that is **not** surrounded by any HTML tags.

For example, this string:

```
<h1>This is the title</h1>This is a bit of text with no HTML around it<p>This is within a paragraph tag</p>
```

Should be converted to:

```
<h1>This is the title</h1><p>This is within a paragraph tag</p>
```

I believe this is best done with regex, although I am not very familiar with it's synax.

All help is greatly appreciated.

---

This is what I ended up using:

```
<?php
$string = '<h1>This is the title</h1>This is a bit of text with no HTML around it<p>This is within a paragraph tag</p>';
$pattern = '/(<\/[^>]+>)[^<]*(<[^>]+>)/';
$replacement = '$1$2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Comment: Seems like not everyone agrees with that http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2947592

Comment: @popovitsj - So are you saying that this is impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use this regex `(<\/[^>]+>)[^<]*(<[^>]+>)` and replace with `$1$2`
live [demo](http://regex101.com/r/tW0vH1)

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for your help! Added a `preg_match` solution to my question.